# [symfony 2]form don't send a file

Tags: php, forms, symfony, file-upload

```
<div id="option-action"> 
  <form  action="{{ path('lab_univer_cpanel') }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
  <table>
      <tr>
      <td><label>Titre</label></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="titre" name="titreNews"></td>
      <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <td><label>Image</label></td>
      <td><input type="file" id="image" name="image" /></td>
      <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <td><label>Contenue</label></td>
      <td><textarea  name="content" ></textarea></td>
      <td></td>
      </tr>
  <div class="submit">
      <input type="submit" name="addNews" value="+" class="addbtn">
  </div>
  </table>    
  </form>
</div>
```

I don't find the file image in the controller

This is the code to get request :

```
if ($req->request->get('addNews')) {
      $titre = $req->request->get('titreNews');
      $content = $req->request->get('content');
      $membre = $em->getRepository('LabUniverBundle:Member')
                   ->findOneBy(array('nom'=>'user'));
      $image = $req->files->get('image');
      print_r($image);
```

The result is a blank page !
I test with an other form like that :

```
<form action="{{ path('lab_univer_cpanel')}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    <input type="file" name="image" />
    <input type="submit" value="send" name="checkUpload" />
</form>
```

It works !!!

Comment: you say it works in an other form,  with the same form treatment (controller code) ? also are you sure you're getting inside your if block ?  and on a meta note, it would be recommended to use FormType so that you don't need to do all the '->get' manually

Comment: - you say it works in an other form, with the same form treatment (controller code) ?   ===>  yes

Comment: also are you sure you're getting inside your if block ===> yes

Comment: use FormType so that you don't need to do all the '->get' manually ===> i create the form manually, i can use it ? how ?

Comment: The problem is when i make a print_r($file); die(); the result is a blank page !!

Comment: for forms , see http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#handling-form-submissions , next things I see now is that your html is not valid (you have a div in the table, but inside no td. also if you're using symfony2.6 , make yourself a favor and use "dump" instead of print_r + die http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-6-vardumper-component

Comment: Thinks broth i will try now